# Should wax for G-1000 be continuously applied?

Tags: clothing, gear-care

I got a Fjällräven Barents Trousers for Christmas! Hell yeah! It's made of the "G-1000" material.

> 65% polyester, 35% cotton. G-1000 Original is the original fabric in
>   Fjällräven’s comfortable outdoor clothing. It started as a tent fabric
>   that proved to be too heavy for lightweight tents. Tested under
>   conditions including everything from Arctic and sub-Arctic expeditions
>   to coffee breaks on sharp stones in forest glades.

You should take care of this kind of material with the Greenland Wax.

> Greenland Wax is the impregnation that is used for all of Fjällräven’s
>   G-1000 products. The wax has been produced since the late 1960s by the
>   same Swedish family business. The recipe is secret but the ingredients
>   are simple: pure paraffin and high-quality beeswax. This makes
>   Greenland Wax a more environmentally friendly alternative than
>   chemical-based impregnation products.

However, I wondered if I should apply the wax continuously? Like "Wax it at least once per month." or something. Or is it more like "on the fly": "Okay, I'm going to wear it tomorrow and it may get wet. Let's apply some wax."

Comment: Does the wax build up, or does it come out in the wash?  If it comes out in the wash, I'd wax after washing and/or whenever you get a bit damp through the trousers.  By the way, what happened with the sweater?

Comment: @ab2 Still stinking... Washed it once again and it's drying atm. However, I think that the answer on the question is right: "bring it back!" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I own a couple of different Fjällräven items (trousers, jacket, hat, duffel) and a number of my friends do as well. While my personal experience with the Greenland wax is limited, it is my understanding, that you can basically personalize your items to your specific need using more or less wax.

- More wax means more water repellent, stiffer material (less wear & tear).
- Less wax means more breathability, and lighter & more flexible fabric.

According to Fjällräven you can also easily wash out any applied wax by washing your G-1000 piece at 40°C. This means you could basically decide before every use which properties you want from your G-1000 fabric, and then apply wax accordingly.

Examples of what I did:

- Fjällräven hat: applied a lot of wax to make it somewhat waterproof and usable in the rain. The hat got a bit stiffer also, which was a good thing to prevent the brim from flopping about.
- Fjällräven winter coat: I did not apply any wax, as I mostly wear this coat when it's too cold for rain and snow can just be brushed off.